# How to open new Estimate created by QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc, qbxml

Hello
I am a web developer
On my web page there is an IRequestProcessor2 object and few JavaScript functions to work with him.
I can create new Estimate in QuickBooks by QBXML query.
Now I need to activate QuickBooks window automatically and open that Estimate
Is there possible by QBXML (or QBFC)?
And how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TxnDisplayMod command to open the Edit Estimate window within QuickBooks. The qbXML syntax looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <TxnDisplayModRq>
      <!-- TxnDisplayModType may have one of the following values: Bill, BillPaymentCheck, BillPaymentCreditCard, BuildAssembly, Charge, Check, CreditCardCharge, CreditCardCredit, CreditMemo, Deposit, Estimate, InventoryAdjustment, Invoice, ItemReceipt, JournalEntry, PurchaseOrder, ReceivePayment, SalesOrder, SalesReceipt, SalesTaxPaymentCheck, VendorCredit -->
      <TxnDisplayModType >ENUMTYPE</TxnDisplayModType> <!-- required -->
      <TxnID >IDTYPE</TxnID> <!-- required -->
    </TxnDisplayModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

From the QuickBooks SDK documentation:

> A TxnDisplayMod request opens a
>   QuickBooks transaction within the
>   QuickBooks UI for modification.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I have no time to try this but neverthless thank you!